# Apply a class with Angular data

Tags: angularjs

I have an item in my array that is `true` or `false`.

I use this to say

```
 <div ng-show="{{ item.isDirectory }}">
```

I also want to use the same rule to apply a class to that div if `item.isDirectory == true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it's incorrect:

```
<div ng-show="{{ item.isDirectory }}">
```

`ngShow` waits an expression, it works just as below:

```
<div ng-show="item.isDirectory">
```

Also, preferably use `ngIf` directive as a good practice.

To apply a class in your div based on a condition, you should use [**`ngClass`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'yourTrueclass': item.isDirectory, 'yourFalseClass': !item.isDirectory }"></div>
```

Take a look on this [**tutorial**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass).

Comment: Ok great, and what if I wanted to apply a class if item is NOT a directory?

Comment: One more question. If I also have a class that applies to all (no conditions) what is the best way? Add it to the `ng-class`? Adding `class=""` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well, if you have a static class it should work with `class`.. can you show me how you're doing it?

Comment: I mean I have a class as well as an Angular class check... `<div class="something" ng-class="{ 'yourTrueclass': item.isDirectory}">`

Comment: Nevermind, I see that should work, but not in my code. Will try and work it out. Thanks.